# Парсинг нескольких страниц

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

Подскажите где у меня ошибка.

Парсит только первую страницу

```
<?php

header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Accept, Content-Type");
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='OPTIONS') exit;

include_once('curl_query.php');
include_once('simple_html_dom.php');

function parser($url, $start, $end) {
    if($start < $end) {
        $file = str_get_html($url);
        $courses = $file->find('.movie-title, 0');
        foreach($courses as $article) {
            $one = curl_get($article->href);
            $one_dom = str_get_html($one);
            $title = $one_dom->find('h1', 0)->text(); // Название
            echo "$title" .'<br>';
        }

        $next = $file->find('.navigation')->next()->find('a')->attr('href');
        if( !empty($next) ) {
            $start++;
            parser($next, $start, $end);
        }
    }
}

$url = curl_get("https://uakino.club/film/");
$start = 0;
$end = 4;
parser($url, $start, $end);
```

Comment: несколько странно использовать рекурсию для парсинга  страниц, вам не кажется?

Comment: Я только учусь) Делал по видео урокам, подскажите как тогда правильно сделать!